# How come I can't access my state in my googleapi oauth2 callback?

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am trying to pass some state along while logging through google with OAuth2.  I create my url:

```
oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: "email",
    state: {
      whatever: 'stupid'
    }
  });
```

And when I hit my callback code

```
router.get("/callback", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
  ...
});
```

My state is not attached to the url and I can't see it in the params.  What am I missing to be able to access this state?